# Change Model Data In a Controller Method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to change data in my model based on choices that a user makes in the view. I have the ajax query below that grabs the drop down values selected and passes them to the controller. I'm trying to change the price value in the model and save it permanently so I can display the price to the user. Currently it calls the method correctly and I inserted a breakpoint and I can see that it has the current price in the value but when the method returns, it doesn't display anything at all. I'm new to MVC so I appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#urgencyList').change(function () {
        var modelData = {
            documentType: $("#documentTypeList").val(),
            urgency: $("#urgencyList").val(),
            numberOfPages: $("#numberOfPagesList").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: modelData,
            url: "/Home/getNewPrice",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = data.currentPrice;
            }
        });
    });

        <div id="priceLabel">
            <h2>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
            </h2>
        </div>
```

Here is my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is Required.")]
    [Range(0.01, 10000.00, ErrorMessage = "Your quote is not complete because you haven't completed all of the steps.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Here is my controller code:

```
    public decimal currentPrice { get; set; }
    public string defaultCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal extraFee { get; set; }
    public decimal pricePerPage { get; set; }

    WritingAppModel model = new WritingAppModel();

    public JsonResult getNewPrice(modelData dropdownValues)
    {
        // check for urgency first since that is the base price
        if (dropdownValues.urgency != null)
        {
            currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dropdownValues.urgency);

            if (dropdownValues.documentType != null)
            {
                currentPrice = currentPrice + Convert.ToDecimal(dropdownValues.documentType);

                if (dropdownValues.numberOfPages != null)
                {
                    currentPrice = currentPrice * Convert.ToInt16(dropdownValues.numberOfPages);
                }
            }
        }

        currentPrice = Math.Round(currentPrice, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        model.Price = currentPrice;
        // do something with value and return a decimal
        return Json(new { currentPrice = model.Price }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: In your `getNewPrice` action you seem to be using some `model` variable which is unclear where it is defined. Same stands true for the `currentPrice` variable.

Comment: Wrap the script in `$(document).ready()` or place it at the bottom of the page (the element does not yet exist when the script is rendered)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh it is but I just forgot to copy and paste it here. I just edited my post with that info

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I edited the code to show where I referenced that from. It was just something I was trying to see if I could get something to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price, new { id = "priceLabel" })
```

doesn't do what you think it does. The `id` is passed as additional view data to the display template but it doesn't set an `id` attribute on the corresponding HTML element which is what you need. Look at the generated HTML markup in your browser and you will see that there's no element with this `id`. So obviously `document.getElementById('priceLabel')` will simply return `null` and you get a javascript error (which you would have seen in your browser if you opened the console in the development toolbar).

So you might need a DOM element with the correct `id`:

```
<div id="priceLabel">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
</div>
```

and in your `success` callback since you already use jQuery you may try replacing:

```
document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = data.currentPrice;
```

with:

```
$('#priceLabel').html(data.currentPrice);
```

Comment: Ok that seemed to fix the issue of the price not showing up but at the same time it also seemed to negate the formatting that I had set for the price. I'm also unsure why the <h2></h2> tags I have placed around it no longer work

Comment: If you want to preserve the formatting you need to do that in your controller: `return Json(new { currentPrice = model.Price.ToString("C") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. Also if you want to use `h2` tags you no longer need the div. Simply use `<h2 id="priceLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)</h2>`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have a question about the model data that I set. I have another dropdown on the same page and if the user changes the value then it is supposed to change the price based on what currency they choose. It is reading the model data but it is always coming up as 0.